# SQL: Get duplicates in same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table:

```
name  email              number  type
1     abc@example.com     10     A
1     abc@example.com     10     B
2     def@def.com         20     B
3     ggg@ggg.com         30     B
1     abc@example.com     10     A
4     hhh@hhh.com         60     A
```

I want the following:

**Result**

```
name  email              number  type
1     abc@example.com     10     A
1     abc@example.com     10     B
1     abc@example.com     10     A
```

Basically, I want to find the first lines where the three columns (name, email, number) are identical and see them, regardless of type.

How can I achieve this in SQL? I **don't want** a result with every combination once, I want to see every line that is in the table multiple times.

I thought of doing a group by but a group by gives me only the unique combinations and every line once. I tried it with a join on the table itself but somehow it got too bloated.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I want to display the **type** column as well, so group by isn't working and therefore, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use exists for that case :

```
select t.*
from table t 
where exists (select 1 
              from table 
              where name = t.name and email = t.email and 
                    number = t.number and type <> t.type);
```

You can also use window function if your *DBMS* support

```
select * 
from (select *, count(*) over (partition by name, email, number) Counter 
      from table
     ) t
where counter > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by name, email, number) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

If you only want combos that have different *types* (which might be your real problem), I would suggest `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 
              from t t2
              where t2.name = t.name and t2.email = t.email and t2.number = t.number and t2.type <> t.type
             );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(name, email, number, type)` for this version.

Comment: I tried this one and the query was just going on for too long. My table is 100.000 lines long, so maybe that is why.

Answer (score 1):

Core SQL-99 compliant solution.

Have a sub-query that returns name, email, number combinations having duplicates. JOIN with that result:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select name, email, number
      from tablename
      group by name, email, number
      having count(*) > 1) t2
on  t1.name = t2.name
and t1.email = t2.email
and t1.number = t2.number
```